# Django - User Defined Queryset Filtering

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am working on an application where end users need to be able to define queryset filters through an interface. These filters are used to select instances of a model to ship off to another web service at timed intervals. Contrived example:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    stuff = models.CharField()
```

I need users to be able to configure a timed task where only `Thing`s with a value of `test` for the `stuff` field will be selected.

I currently have a working POC for this functionality, but it involves a lot of hand coded logic.

Given that django has such a rich community and ecosystem, I was wondering if I am missing an opportunity to do this in a simpler way.

Looking forward to your feedback!

Comment: Based on a saved filter, you could configure the timed tasks: https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your requirements correctly:

- A user must be able to configure a filter which specifies which `Thing`s should be selected - without any programming knowledge, just through a GUI
- A user must be able to set up timed tasks and specify which web service is targeted and which filter should be used to send the appropriate data

Based on this premises, i would:

- Use https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters
- Create a Model/Form/View for `TimedTasks` which contain the relation to `AdvancedFilter` and the webservice specs
- Retrieve the data through `AdvancedFilter#query` in the task runner, set up and call the webservice

This way the user can use the Overview page of `Thing` to create his data filters, and can link them in the creation of `TimedTask` along with the webservice config.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough breakdown. I actually have the timed tasks handled already (provided that info just for context), I just need a way to provide a GUI for the filter selection (which meets the requirements you laid out). Going to check out advanced filters, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, Django 2.X support is not merged into master quite yet. Nonetheless, this fits my needs exactly, thanks!

Comment: yw! I see they are on it, let's hope they will be quick :)